# Why removing a printf function messes up with my code? CS50 pset1 cash greedy challenge

Tags: cs50, greedy, printf-debugging

I finished the challenge and my first C code worked apparently well, returning each time the correct minimum number of coins needed for change. Then when I tried to "clean it up" a bit and remove a redundant printf, everything seems to go to wrong. I cannot get my brains around this one, I am very confused...  Why does this happen?

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int q = 25; //variable for quarters
int d = 10; //dimes
int n = 5;  //nickels
int p = 1;  //pennies

int x;  //variable for final result
int r;  // variable for the reminder

float amount(string prompt);

int main(void)
{
    float a = amount("Enter dollar amount with format 0.00: $");
    int cents = round(a * 100);
    printf("Your input: $ %.2f", a);
    // printf(", which amounts to %i total.\n", cents); //WHY DELETING THIS LINE MESSES UP WITH THE FLOAT AND THE RESULT?

    x = cents / q;
    r = cents % q;

    x = x + (r / d);
    r = r % d;

    x = x + (r / n);
    r = r % n;

    x = x + (r / p);
    printf("%i\n", x);
    r = r % p;
    printf("%i\n", r);
}

float amount(string prompt)
{
    float a;
    do {
        a = get_float("%s", prompt);
    }
    while (a <= 0);
    return a;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you remove the print statement? What specifically goes wrong?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment.  Someone else pointed out what was wrong, it was something quite obvious but I couldn't see it!  Basically as I was missing the line break \n the result of the exercise would come next and looked to me as an extra digit on the input and the result missing... quite embarrasing, learning to code is being one of the most humbling experiences I can remember haha. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

It was a little thing but I just couldn't see it... 
Removing that estatement without adding a line break above would bring the answer right after the input, so it looked to me as a misterious extra digit and missing solution (embarrasing I know...hah). Basically:

```
 $ ./cash3
Enter dollar amount with format 0.00: $1.12
7
0
```

...became...

```
Enter dollar amount with format 0.00: $1.12
Your input: $ 1.127
0
```

Sometimes looking to close to the trees make you miss the whole forest lol
Thanks to Blauelf for his help and solution with this!